# Flat morphisms whose fibers are affine spaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, intersection-theory, fibre-bundles

Let $f:X \to Y$ be a flat morphism, such that each fiber is isomorphic to the affine space $\mathbb{A}^n$. Then is is true that $f$ is a Zariski affine bundle? If not, is it at least an  ètale affine bundle?

If not, is there some reasonable natural ipotesis to add to make this true?

My definition of affine bundle is a map $f:X \to Y$ such that there is an open cover ${U_{\alpha}}$ of $Y$ with $f^{-1} U_{\alpha} \cong U_{\alpha} \times \mathbb{A}^n$, and $f$ restricted to $f^{-1}(U_{\alpha})$ corresponds to the first projection.

The question is somewhat related to:
[Affine bundles over varieties](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54502/affine-bundles-over-varieties)

Comment: Did you check Angelo's answer to http://mathoverflow.net/questions/58009/non-locally-trivial-an-bundles
?

It seems to be very related to your question

Comment: If instad of the affine space you would have the protective one, than I think that the answer s positive. If you are interested I can try to write a proof

Comment: @Rami: In the case of projective spaces, it is only true for étale localisation (not Zariski). Such fibrations are called Severi-Brauer schemes.

Comment: ...although: what I said in my comment applies if the fibres are *geometrically* projective spaces. Maybe what you say works if the fibres are actually projective spaces.

Comment: @Damian: no, this is false even if fibers are actually projective spaces (over an algebraically closed field). A standard example: if $X\subset\mathbb P^4$ is a smooth cubic, then, projecting it from a line $\ell\subset X$ to $\mathbb P^2$, we obtain a morphism $\tilde X\to\mathbb P^2$ (where $\tilde X$ is the blow-up of $X$ at $\ell$). Over a Zariski open subset of $\mathbb P^2$, all its fibers are smooth plane conics (so they are isomorphic to $\mathbb P^1$). If it were a locally trivial bundle in Zariski topology, $X$ would be rational, which is not the case.

Comment: @Rami. Thanks a lot for pointing out the other related question.

@Damian. What reference do you recommend for Severi-Brauer schemes?

Comment: The basic reference for Severi-Brauer schemes is Grothendieck, 
"Le groupe de Brauer I" in "Dix exposés sur la cohomologie 
des schémas" (a collection of essays published by North-Holland).
@Lvovski: thank you for the interesting example.

Comment: @Lvovski: on second thoughts: is the *generic* fibre of the morphism $\tilde{X}\to{\bf P}^2$ also a projective space over the function field of ${\bf P}^2$ (I don't think so) ? In order to be a counterexample to Rami's statement, that must hold too.

Answer (score 4):

The question is discussed in detail in the paper "Families of group actions, generic isotriviality, and linearization" (Transform. Groups 19 (2014), no. 3, 779–792. MR 3233525) by Peter Russell and myself. There is e.g. an example, due to Nori, of a flat morphism $X \to Y$ with fibers $A^1$ and base $Y$ equal the cuspidal curve which is not locally trivial in the etale topology.